# Rsync Time Machine Style Backup issues

Tags: rsync

I bought an external USB3 drive to backup a WD MyCloud NAS (plugs directly into a USB3 on the NAS), and started searching for an rsync script to simulate a Time Machine style backup.

I found one that I like, but it's not working the way I expected it to.
Therefore I'm hoping you could shed some light on the matter and suggest what could/should be done to, first of all, make it work and second, suggest how this should be done to get a result similar to a Time Machine style snapshot backup.

Where I found the script I started with:

https://bipedu.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/easy-backup-system-with-rsync-like-time-machine/

He breaks down the process like this:

---

> So here I make first a “date” variable that will be used in the name
>   of the backup folder to easily know when that backup/snapshot was
>   made.
>
> Then use the rsync with some parameters (see man rsync for more
>   details):
>
> -a = archive mode ( to send only changed parts)
>
> -P = to give a progress info – (optional)
>
> –delete = to delete the deleted files from backup in case they are
>   removed from source
>
> –log-file = to save the log into a file (optional)
>
> –exclude = to exclude some folders/files from backup . This are
>   relative to source path !!! do not use absolute path here !
>
> –link-dest = link to the latest backup snapshot
>
> /mnt/HD/HD_a2/  = source path
>
> /mnt/USB/USB2_c2/MyCloud/Backups/back-$date  = destination folder , it
>   will contain all the content from the source.
>
> Then by using rm I remove the old link to the old backup ( the
>   “current” link) and then I replace it with a new soft link to the
>   newly created snapshot.
>
> So now whenever I click on “current” I go in fact to the latest backup
>   . And because every time I make the backup the date is different the
>   old snapshots will be kept. So for every day I will have a snapshot.

---

Here is my script version based on his outline.

```
#!/bin/bash
date=`date “+%Y%m%d-%H-%M”`
rsync -aP --delete --log-file=/tmp/log_backup.log --exclude="lost+found" --exclude="Anti-Virus Essentials" --exclude=Nas_Prog --exclude=SmartWare --exclude=plex_conf --exclude=Backup --exclude=TimeMachineBackup --exclude=groupings.db --link-dest=/mnt/USB/USB2_c2/MyCloud/Backups/Current /mnt/HD/HD_a2/ /mnt/USB/USB2_c2/MyCloud/Backups/back-$date
rm -f /mnt/USB/USB2_c2/MyCloud/Backups/Current
ln -s /mnt/USB/USB2_c2/MyCloud/Backups/back-$date /mnt/USB/USB2_c2/MyCloud/Backups/Current
```

So if I am understanding his idea, first initial backup lives here.  /mnt/USB/USB2_c2/MyCloud/Backups/Current.

Then on subsequent backups, the script creates a new directory in the /mnt/USB/USB2_c2/MyCloud/Backups/Current/ named ‘back-2015-12-20T09-19’ or whatever date the backup took place.

This is where I am getting a bit lost on whats **actually** happening.

It writes a time stamped folder to the /Backups/Current/ directory, and ALSO to the /Backups/ directory. So I have 2 versions of those time stamped folders now in two different directories.

Im confused as to where the actual most complete set of recent backup files resides now.

What I THOUGHT was going to happen is that the script would run, and any file that wasn’t changed, it would create a link from the ‘Current’ folder to the time stamped folder.

Im sure I have something wrong here, and hoping someone can point out the error and/or suggest a better method.

Comment: Try this. https://github.com/laurent22/rsync-time-backup

Did you find a solution finally?